# Change the table letter color according to the condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have table with my office shift rota. where it have letters like as shown below but its with out any color.
I want to update the colors as below according to letter dynamically
Ex: AW => yellow, W => red , T => Green, etc ..

[image]

Apologies, not able to copy the code from office machine, provided sample table data.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="EMPLOYEE">Rahul</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D1">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D2">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D3">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D4">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D5">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D6">O</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D7">O</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D8">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D9">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D10">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D11">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D12">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D13">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D14">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D15">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D16">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D17">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D18">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D19">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D20">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D21">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D22">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D23">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D24">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D25">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D26">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D27">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D28">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D29">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D30">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D31"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="EMPLOYEE">Srinivas</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D1">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D2">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D3">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D4">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D5">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D6">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D7">W</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D8">W</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D9">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D10">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D11">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D12">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D13">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D14">W</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D15">W</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D16">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D17">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D18">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D19">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D20">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D21">W</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D22">W</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D23">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D24">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D25">X</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D26">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D27">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D28">W</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D29">W</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D30">A</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D31"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="EMPLOYEE">Rajesh</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D1">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D2">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D3">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D4">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D5">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D6">O</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D7">W</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D8">W</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D9">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D10">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D11">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D12">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D13">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D14">W</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D15">W</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D16">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D17">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D18">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D19">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D20">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D21">W</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D22">W</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D23">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D24">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D25">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D26">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D27">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D28">W</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D29">W</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D30">M</td><td class="t-Report-cell"  headers="D31"></td></tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Please provide your code sir..

Answer (score 0):

An idea could be to add a `data` attribute while dynamically creating the  elements and apply styles depending on it

```
<td data-text="aw">
  AW
</td>
```

```
td[data-text="aw"] {
  background-color: yellow
}
```